# Sharepoint 2010, templates and Features

Tags: site-template, feature-activation

I have been trying to create site templates from a local SP2010 server that can be used by a client for some custom content.  The problem is all the "the site template requires that the feature be activated in the site collection" errors.

For most features, I am able to activate them, and then the error guid changes.  But now I am stuck on a few that dont exist at all -anywhere- on my site.  Not the farm features, site collection features or site features.

An example of this is error guid 5eac763d-fbf5-4d6f-a76b-eded7dd7b0a5.

From multiple blog sites, I see this is the Search Extensions feature, allowing for FAST Search functionality.  But I dont see any feature called 'Search Extensions'.  Is it part of some other feature?  How can I find which one?

I ran into a similar problem for 'My Sites Blog' feature... which I also dont have.

I have full administrator access to this sharepoint server, and have looked everywhere I can think of....

Any suggestions?  Up against the wall on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Features, at any scope, can be hidden from the user interface (Property SPFeatureDefinition.Hidden)

It seems to be your case with your feature with Guid "5eac763d-fbf5-4d6f-a76b-eded7dd7b0a5". A quick Google search reveals this is "FAST Search site collection features" (SearchExtensions), which includes the Visual Best Bets webpart and some site setting pages for FAST Search management.

Take a look at [this blog article](http://www.neilrichards.net/fast/fast-search-site-collection-features-are-not-activated) to see how to find the feature name, and activate it using Powershell on a given site.

Side note: If your template is trying to activate this feature, it will mean FAST search will also need to be licensed/activated on whatever client farm you deploy it on. Is this intended? Perhaps what you need a site definition instead, that you can edit and customize fully.

Comment: Thanks!  I did figure out how to activate these features via powertools... one problem the client will have is they do not have (and do not want) management rights on the farm.  They just want to be the consumer.  So the plan is for me to give them a template without the fluff that hopefully they can create a site with, and can export themselves.